# When dispose a dbcontext in .net core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

im making a project with a persistence layer, domain layer, and business layer, i implementing the generic repository pattern and unit of work with entity framework core.

I want to use this project in a web api rest and in a UWP project.

The correct ways its override the method?, add the context in the startup configureservices? When dispose a dbcontext?

Comment: When the controller is being disposed, call dispose on your repository and that should dispose the context. If you are using a service layer and not talking to the repository directly from the controller, then call dispose on the service which will call dispose on repo which will dispose the context.

Comment: If you are using EF, you do not need unit of work because EF already works that way. Search for this online.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Read documentation on configuring DbContext: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Basically, you add it to your services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}
```

Then you inject it into whatever class you want. An easy example would be inejecting it into a Controller (but you could inject into any class that is added to your services):

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public MyController(BloggingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

The Dependency Injection library will then handle disposal - you do not call Dispose directly. This is described in documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#overview-of-dependency-injection.).

> The framework takes on the responsibility of creating an instance of
>   the dependency and disposing of it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation that can back up this: *The Dependency Injection library will then handle disposal - you do not call Dispose directly.*

Comment: The statement "The Dependency Injection library will then handle disposal" typically applies only to ASP.NET core applications and does NOT apply for other long running applications such as Windows services.
For ASP.NET core DbContext instance is created for each request and disposed when the request ends: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/
This does NOT happen for other types of applications automatically. So for a UWP application, it is necessary to dispose DbContext at the end of the unit-of-work.